# How to Stop Email subject line from auto populating from case feed

Tags: force.com, service-cloud-console, publisher-action

I have created a case. In the feed window of case when i am trying to send a mail. email subject is auto populated with case subject. 
How to stop this ?

[image]

**Thanks

Nirmallya Ghosh**

Answer (score 2):

On your custom publisher action `Setup > App Setup > Customize > Cases > Buttons, Links, Actions` and select the publisher action, add a property in `Predefined Field Values`.

[image]

Here you will select the field you want to pre-define (`Subject` in your case), and define the value (`""` in your case which tells system that the value should be blank). If you want it to default to another value or pull information from the record, you may do so there as well.

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work as of 11/2/2020 in my sandbox, email content is still overwriting